# VLOOKUP-style range lookup in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql, vlookup

Here's a tricky problem I haven't quite been able to get my head around.  I'm using SQL Server 2008, and I have a sparse range table that looks like this:

```
Range     Profession
-----     ----------
0         Office Worker
23        Construction
54        Medical
```

Then I have another table with values that are within these ranges.  I'd like to construct a query which joins these two tables and gives me the Profession value that is less than or equal to the given value.  So let's say my other table looks like this:

```
Value
29
1
60
```

Then I'd like my join to return:

```
Value     Profession
-----     ----------
29        Construction
1         Office Worker
60        Medical
```

(because 29>the 23 for Construction but <=the 54 for Medical)

Is there any way I can get SQL to bend to my will in this manner, short of actually blowing out the range table to include every possible value?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use CROSS APPLY:

```
select v.Value, p.Profession
from tblValues v
cross apply
   (select top(1) pr.Profession
    from tblProfessionRanges pr
    where pr.Range <= v.Value ORDER BY pr.[Range] DESC) p
```

It should be faster than using max and doesn't need a max-range do be maintained.

Comment: Ingenious!  I think this one is the best and simplest answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks to you ... and to Itzik Ben-Gan for it was his idea.

Answer (score 4):

Easist Way to do this is to add a another column to you sparse range table.

```
LowRange       HighRange      Profession
   0              22         Office Worker
  23              53          Construction
  54            999999         Medical
```

Then use a query like this to get the range(table 2 is the one with the 29,1,60 values):

```
SELECT Table_2.JoinKey as Value, Table_1.Description as Profession 
  FROM Table_1 INNER JOIN Table_2 
          ON Table_2.JoinKey => Table_1.LowRangeKey 
             AND Table_2.JoinKey <= Table_1.HighRangeKey;
```

Comment: +1 SQL is a declarative language. Sure, you can query to find the `HighRange` value _each and every time_ you use this table but it never changes so why not just _declare it once_ and be done with it.

Answer (score 2):

I think I understand your problem. I created a table called `professions` with your values and a `map_vals` table with the look up values. Then I came up with this:

```
select p.range as `range1`, p.profession, v.value from professions p 
inner join map_vals v ON v.value >= p.range
where p.range = 
      (select max(p3.range) from professions p3 where p3.range <= v.value) 
order by v.value
```

which when given these values...

```
value   
29
0
60
1
23
54
```

returns

```
range1  profession  value   
0           Office Worker   0
0           Office Worker   1
23          Construction    23
23          Construction    29
54          Medical         54
54          Medical         60
```

### EDIT:

You could also use CROSS APPLY as shown by [manfred-sorg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/494418/manfred-sorg) but it requires an `ORDER BY DESC` or you will get the following:

```
select v.Value, p.Profession
from tblValues v
cross apply
   (select top(1) pr.Profession
    from tblProfessionRanges pr
    where pr.Range <= v.Value) p
```

produces

```
Value       Profession
----------- --------------------------------------------------
29          Office Worker
1           Office Worker
60          Office Worker
```

to get your desired result you need to change it to:

```
select v.Value, p.Profession
from tblValues v
cross apply
   (select top(1) pr.Profession
    from tblProfessionRanges pr
    where pr.Range <= v.Value ORDER BY pr.[Range] DESC) p

Value       Profession
----------- --------------------------------------------------
29          Construction
1           Office Worker
60          Medical
```

However, the sorting required here makes it less efficient than using `MAX`.